# Android ListView - change background of element based on values

Tags: android, listview, background

I have a list which lists EXPENSES and INCOMES. I want ListViewer to automatically change background to either green for Incomes or red for Expenses, would this be possible?

```
final DbCon database = new DbCon(this);
        final ListView Viewer = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.historyViewer);
        //date1, time1, desc1, val1, cat1, type1
        final SimpleAdapter La = new SimpleAdapter(this, database.GetMonths(), R.layout.mviewer, new String[] {"month"}, new int[] {R.id.month_name});
        Viewer.setAdapter(La);
```

Comment: Yes, nearly anything is possible. It just takes an attempt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176398/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-list-items-based-on-the-data-being-disp

Comment: In your `Adapters` `getView()` method you would change it according to the current values as in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any code, its hard to give any "real" help but it is possible. You can change the background color with something like

```
rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

assuming `rowView` is your current `View` in the `List`. You can also change `styles` and `themes` depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just put the logic in the getView method of your Adapter, e.g.:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View myView;

   if(convertView == null) {
       myView = new MyView();
} else {
     myView = (MyView) convertView;
}

if(myList.get(position).isExpense) {
    myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
} else {
   myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
   return myView;       

}
```

**edit:**

Yes, I see that you are using a `SimpleAdapter`. That will not be sufficient to do what you want. You need to create your own adapter by subclassing `BaseAdapter` (or something similar) and overriding the necessary methods, e.g. `getView` as I showed above.