# Android ListView Adapter adding views

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm attempting to change the color of certain items in a ListView. It crashes with a NullPointerException, I'm not exactly sure why, I think it's because the Adapter hasn't created/added the view to the ListView, so it's trying to retrieve an item that isn't on the array. Whenever there is at least 1 item on the list, I am able to add the colored items perfectly fine. How can I resolve this?

```
        int index = 0;
    for(ItemEntry i: tentry) {
        adapter.add(i.Name); // Adding to Adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Telling it I've done so
        long time = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(i.Date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis());
        ListView stuff = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.contentsList);
        if( time < 0 ) {
            stuff.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // Null exception
        } else if( time < 1 ) {
            stuff.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // Null exception
        } else if( time < 2 ) {
            stuff.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); // Null exception
        }
        index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reach into children by index to make UI changes like this.  It's begging for trouble:

```
stuff.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // Null exception
```

Instead, make changes to the item views in the getView() of your adapter based on some logic that determines which individual items should have what background color.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this kind of logic in the getView method of your Adapter.
There you can modify the backgroundColor of the item depending on its value.

There are many threads on this topic. 
For example take a look here: [How can I change the background color of list items based on the data being displayed in each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176398/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-list-items-based-on-the-data-being-disp)